# Content-Security-Policy: allow custom URI

Tags: image, content-security-policy

I'm currently trying to implement CSP for our web application. There's also a mobile application that uses various web endpoints. The mobile application loads custom resources that look like this:

```
ma-file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{GUID}
```

I've set the 'default-src' directive and want to override it with 'img-src' so that allows all images, including those custom ones. This is my 'img-src' directive

```
img-src * data: blob: filesystem:;
```

According to [this reference](https://content-security-policy.com/#source_list) it should cover all cases, but I still get a policy violation for the specified custom URI. The CSP report states

```
"violated-directive":"img-src * data: blob: filesystem:"
```

Please advise how I can allow these images.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "ma-file:" to your source list for img-src. This works in Chrome, where it seems like you can specify any custom scheme. I don't know if it works in other browsers.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but I continue to receive CSP violation reports. Unfortunately the report does not say what the browser is.